# How to use the KKT-conditions for a not-differentiable function using subdifferentials.

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

First some notation. Let $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \textbf{x}} f(\textbf{x})$ determine the gradient for a funcion $f:\textbf{R}^n \rightarrow \textbf{R}$, and let the subdifferential be determined by $\dfrac{\partial_s}{\partial_s \textbf{x}} f(\textbf{x})$. Remark that the subdifferential is the set of all subgradients.

Now imagine we are in an optimization setting, where $f$ is the objective function, $g_i$ is an inequality constraint  function for $i = 1, \ ..., m_1$ and $h_i$ is an equality constraint function for $i = 1, \ ..., m_2$. Let $\textbf{k}$ be the vector of lagrange-multipliers for the inequality constraints, and let $\textbf{l}$ be the ditto for the equality constraints. Then if all the functions are differentiable, [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions#Necessary_conditions) wikipedia site gives the following KKT-conditions:

\begin{align}
 && &\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \textbf{x}} f(\tilde{\textbf{x}}) + 
 \sum_{i=1}^{m_1}k_i\dfrac{\partial}{\partial 
  \textbf{x}}g_i(\tilde{\textbf{x}}) + \sum_{j=1}^{m_2}l_j \dfrac{\partial}{\partial 
  \textbf{x}}h_j(\tilde{\textbf{x}}) = 0. && \text{Stationarity condition}\\
 && &g_i(\tilde{\textbf{x}}) \leq 0, \qquad i = 1, \ ..., m_1. && \text{Primal feasibility condition I}\\
 && &h_j(\tilde{\textbf{x}}) = 0, \qquad j = 1, \ ..., m_2. && \text{Primal feasibility condition II}\\
 && &k_i \geq 0, \qquad i = 1, \ ..., m_1. && \text{Dual feasibility condition}\\
 && &k_ig_i(\tilde{\textbf{x}}) = 0, \qquad i = 1, \ ..., m_1. && \text{Complementary slackness 
  condition}\\
 \end{align}
The wiki-article then goes on to make the following remark:

> If some of the functions are non-differentiable, subdifferential versions of Karush–Kuhn–Tucker (KKT) conditions are available

I imagine that means if either one of $f$, the $g_i$'s and the $h_i$ are not differentiable, we exchange the stationarity condition with:
\begin{align}
&& &0 \in \dfrac{\partial_s}{\partial_s \textbf{x}} f(\tilde{\textbf{x}}) + 
 \sum_{i=1}^{m_1}k_i\dfrac{\partial_s}{\partial_s 
  \textbf{x}}g_i(\tilde{\textbf{x}}) + \sum_{j=1}^{m_2}l_j \dfrac{\partial_s}{\partial_s 
  \textbf{x}}h_j(\tilde{\textbf{x}}), && 
\end{align}
where the subgradients are uniquely determined by the gradient, for the functions who are still differentiable. However I have a very hard time verifying this. I have looked in my usual nonlinear-programming go-to books (Bertsekas "Nonlinear Programming" and "Convex Optimization" by Boyd and Vanderberghe) without any luck, since these books only deal with differentiable functions. The wikipage links to the following source:

> Ruszczyński, Andrzej (2006). Nonlinear Optimization. Princeton, NJ: Princeton University Press. ISBN 978-0691119151. MR 2199043.

However, I do not have acces to this book.

**So my question is this:**
First of all, is my understanding of the comment on the wikipedia-page correct?
Secondly, does anyone have a source where I can read a proof for this?

**Context:** I am asking this question, since I am writing an assignment about constrained estimation of the LASSO-estimator whose error function is not differentiable in parts of it's domain.

Answer (score 1):

In Hastie, Tibshirani and Wainwright "Statistical Learning with Sparsity" page 99 equation (5.11) in section 5.2.2 they use the generalized KKT-conditions in the special case of the Lasso-estimator. I am going to refer to this in my assignment, even though it isn't proved in this book.

If anyone stumbles across this question and know a place, where it is proved, please do let me know.